# Laravel SMTP mailtrap [Connection timed out #110]

Tags: laravel-5, swiftmailer

I'm trying to send email with Laravel using mailtrap for testing in a local homestead server.

The firewall shows no rules blocking port 2525.

Mail driver config:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=$USERNAME
MAIL_PASSWORD=$PASSWORD
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

Error returned:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Swift_TransportException' with message 'Connection could not be established with host mailtrap.io [Connection timed out #110]'
```

Comment: If you try `telnet mailtrap.io 2525` does it work?

Comment: After fighting with this for hours, I found out that if I change the host to the IPv4 address, it works.

Comment: So you have a name resolution issue. Note that `mailtrap.io` is handled by Google for the mail and has 5 MX records.

Comment: `On 8 March 2018 Mailtrap blocked the traffic from “mailtrap.io”`

Switching to the new host and restarting the system solved the DNS problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your hostname is invalid. It should be `smtp.mailtrap.io`. More info here: https://mailtrap.io/blog/2018-03-09-why-mailtrap-updated-its-smtp-host

P.S. Mailtrap doesn't have static IP addresses, so your way with IPv4 will work not so long amount of time.

Comment: This appears to have solved the problem! I'm not sure why before it was returning the same error with a different host name, but I completely restarted the system and it started to function properly again. Thank you!

Comment: How do you handle this error for the end-user? I mean, how do you catch this error and redirect to another page where the user can either try again or report this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Alexey Vasiliev answer , after you fix the hostname don't forget to clear the cache using the following commands

```
php artisan config:clear 
php artisan cache:clear
```

Comment: How do you handle this error for the end-user? I mean, how do you catch this error and redirect to another page where the user can either try again or report this issue?